# Detect changes made to VPS linux image by hosting company

Tags: linux, debian, security, vps, hardening

My VPS hosting company injects "extras" into new Debian (and other) VPS images - scripts, network config, telemetry, etc.

How can I compare a new VPS against the official image, to see what changes were made by the hosting company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the easiest way is to just ask them. They should document this?

Absent that, start by looking under /usr/local for things; it might be limited to those.

Check if they installed any packages that aren't in any repositories; the easiest way to do that, in my opinion, is to fire up `aptitude` and look under the "Obsolete and Locally Created Packages" section. If that doesn't show up anything, check your apt configuration; they might have created a package repository for your local packages (

Next, you can look for files that aren't in any packages:

```
for i in /usr/bin/*; do dpkg -S $i >/dev/null 2>&1 || dpkg -S /bin/$(basename $i) >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "$i not found"; done
```

will give you a line like

```
/usr/bin/myvps-specific-command not found
```

for anything found in /usr/bin that isn't in any Debian package. Note the second dpkg call with the `$(basename $i)` construction to search for programs that are found in `/bin` but not in `/usr/bin`; this is necessary because of the usrmerge stuff, otherwise you'll get a bunch of false positives (so don't leave it out).

You can repeat the above for other directories, e.g., `/usr/sbin` etc (and then also update the second dpkg call).

In case your provider did something really weird, you can check if the checksums of any installed program differ:

```
cd /
LC_ALL=C sudo md5sum -c var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums | grep -v 'OK$'
```

This will necessarily get you a few false positives (there are some files that must be modified after install), but it should get you started.

Comment: Thanks. So to your knowledge, there's no automated way to compare a running debian to the image from which it was installed - this is the sort of thing I must do manually? (And hope I'm good enough to find all the changes.)

Comment: Not that I know of, no. But again, your provider should give you this kind of information -- have you tried asking them?

Comment: Yes, they either lie, or are incompetent so they give the wrong info. I suspect this will be a serious problem going forward for many VPS hosters.